# mod_rewrite condition if path has two stings

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

What I would like to do is to get value from path in case where are only two values. Ex.

`127.0.0.1/myApp/<anyName>` and should be translated to `127.0.0.1/myApp/SubApp/Controller/Test/Index.php?name=<anyName>`

I did this

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /myApp/SubApp/Controller/Test/Index.php?name=$1 [L]
```

But now I have conflict in my second rule, which translate

```
127.0.0.1/myApp/Test/TestPage/1/text
```

to `127.0.0.1/myApp/SubApp/Controller/Test/TestPage.php?id=1&string=text&...`

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/myApp/SubApp/Controller/[^/]+/[^/]+\.php
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?(.*)$ /myApp/SubApp/Controller/$1/$2.php/$3 [L]
```

How to solve this issue

Comment: I don't see any code here that translates to `?id=1&string=text&...`

Comment: If you can't skip in your existing rule anything beginning with just /myApp/SubApp/Controller, then add a special case as an [OR] for the Controller/Test/.*\.php.